# Column wise Distinct count in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, count, distinct

I have a table in SQL like below:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
[StoreID] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
[Barcode] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
[1] [float] NULL,
[2] [float] NULL,
[3] [float] NULL,
[4] [float] NULL,
[5] [float] NULL,
[6] [float] NULL,
[7] [float] NULL
) 
GO

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test] ([StoreID], [Barcode], [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7])
    VALUES ('S1','B1',4,4,4,4,5,5,3),
           ('S1','B2',4,4,0,4,1,4,4),
           ('S2','B1',0,0,0,0,0,1,1)
```

[image]

I need to have distinct count of columns 1 to 7, so the expected result would look like below:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have only 3 rows, where would those counts come from? What are you trying to count? Does `row wise` actually mean *column wise*? You can't do that. Aggregation in SQL, the language, is across rows, not columns. A table isn't a grid or a spreadsheet. Each column is a completely different attribute. The table you created has 9 attributes, StoreID, BarCode and 7 very weirdly named attributes, 1-7. Why was such a table created in the first place?

Comment: To perform a distinct count you'd have to use [UNPIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15#unpivot-example) to convert the data to `StoreId,Barcode, AttributeNum,Value` and group by `StoreId,BarCode,AttributeNum`. Then you'd have to PIVOT to get the data back in the original shape. The problem isn't SQL, it's the way the original table is designed

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You're right...I have edited the title...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another possible solution is to unpivot the values from each row using `VALUES` table-value constructor and an `APPLY` oprator:

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Test] t
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT v)
   FROM (VALUES (t.[1]), (t.[2]), (t.[3]), (t.[4]), (t.[5]), (t.[6]), (t.[7])) v (v)
) a (DistinctCount)
```

Result:

```
StoreID Barcode 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 DistinctCount
-------------------------------------------
S1      B1      4 4 4 4 5 5 3 3
S1      B2      4 4 0 4 1 4 4 3
S2      B1      0 0 0 0 0 1 1 2
```

Answer (score 2):

One option uses a union to unpivot your data into separate rows, followed by an aggregation:

```sql
SELECT StoreID, Barcode, COUNT(DISINCT val) AS DistinctCount
FROM
(
    SELECT StoreID, Barcode, [1] AS val FROM Test UNION ALL
    SELECT StoreID, Barcode, [2] FROM Test UNION ALL
    SELECT StoreID, Barcode, [3] FROM Test UNION ALL
    SELECT StoreID, Barcode, [4] FROM Test UNION ALL
    SELECT StoreID, Barcode, [5] FROM Test UNION ALL
    SELECT StoreID, Barcode, [6] FROM Test UNION ALL
    SELECT StoreID, Barcode, [7] FROM Test
) t
GROUP BY
    StoreID,
    Barcode;
```

Note: Your value columns are actually floats, which means that they are *not* exact values.  So, it's perfectly possible that each record in your source table could always have 7 distinct values.  If you want exact comparison of numeric values, use an exact type, such as `DECIMAL`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution that takes advantage of `openjon` to pivot and count the values

```
select * 
from Test t
cross apply(
    select Count(distinct value) from OpenJson((
        select * from Test x 
        where x.storeId=t.storeId and x.barcode=t.barcode
        for json auto,without_array_wrapper
    ))
    where Try_Cast([key] as int)is not null
)c(DistinctCount)
```